# uninitialized constant Wing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I am trying to run test case for model using Rspec and Factory girl it is showing uninitialized constant Wing
 code in factories/wing.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :wing do
    wing_name "Example Title"
    is_deleted "0"
    mg_school_id "1"
    created_by "2013-06-02 02:28:12"
    updated_by "2013-06-02 02:28:12"
  end 
end
```

code in model/mg_wing_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MgWing, type: :model do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    @hai=FactoryGirl.create(:wing)
  end
end
```

Comment: your model name should be wing.rb

Comment: name of the model is mg_wing.rb

Comment: it should be wing.rb. which tutorial or article do you following to create app . please add that article or tutorial in question

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/learn-the-first-best-practices-for-rails-and-rspec/

Comment: update it in question

Comment: in the factory change the name `mg_wing.rb` and also replace this line `factory :wing do` with `factory :mb_wing do` you model name and spec should always be same

Comment: @ShashikalaReddy check my answer below.

Comment: I am not telling to change the model name , i am telling to change her factory name. @araratan first see and than tell

Comment: This should do `factory :wing, class: MgWing do`

Comment: @Vishal, yeah right. Let me tag your comment as helpful.

Comment: thankyou @vishal,Deepak It working fine..........

Comment: @ShashikalaReddy glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change filename `factories/wing.rb` to `factories/mg_wing.rb`

Your factory name should be the same in your model and rspec filename.

Here are a couple of tutorials if you want it:

https://medium.com/@JonoYeong/setting-up-rspec-and-factory-girl-8cf287801099

https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/working-effectively-with-data-factories-using-factorygirl

Comment: @ShashikalaReddy, It seems that my answer helped you, please accept or upvote my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You either need the factory name same as the model name or pass the `class` param and factorygirl will take care of it

Solution 1

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :mg_wing do
    ...
  end 
end
```

Solution 2

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :wing, class: MgWing do
    ...
  end 
end
```